# Using the data from current request only

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a page where i enter the data and save it on the model and simultaneously some other event occurs lets say some other data creation is happening with the data for this i am using a query .all() how can i limit the creation to the current request.

```
def some_method():
    for x in mymodel.M2Mfields.all()
```

this is creation happens for all the data in the model how can i limit the data creation to be happening only with the current data entered on the page rather than all in the model which are previously entered

Comment: Please add the view and relevant model(s) and methods to your question. Do you want to iterate over  __only__ the entries created in the request or the existing data + created data?

Comment: @IainShelvington its only for the current request and not the existing data

Comment: Use filter with values from request data, it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in a view, then use it like this:

```
def some_method(request):
    for x in mymodel.M2Mfields.filter(some_field=request.user)
```

I assume that `mymodel.some_field` is a `ForeignKey` to `User` instance.